# swagger.exe tofile command will launch with executing assembly, dotnet-swagger.dll

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, .net-5, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

So I am upgrading my api's from Dotnet 3.1 to Dotnet 5. I setup a test on my build server to check if the swagger documentation is compiling correctly using `swagger.exe tofile`. But this element is now giving problems.

First I have XML Comments enabled, so that they get included in swagger. I implemented this using the following code, copied from the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments).

```
c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Name + ".xml"));
```

Now while this all works fine when running the API, when you compile using the swagger CLI to output to a file it crashes (see error below).

```
swagger.exe tofile --output "swagger.json" "WebApplication3.dll" v1
```

**But as you can see in the error the EntryAssembly get set to dotnet-swagger.dll. While I could just hardcode it, I am looking for a better solution to fix it. ? Or is this a bug in the .NET 5 version?**

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\EXJ508\source\repos\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\bin\Debug\net5.0\dotnet-swagger.xml'.
File name: 'C:\Users\EXJ508\source\repos\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\bin\Debug\net5.0\dotnet-swagger.xml'
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SwaggerGenOptionsExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<IncludeXmlComments>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SwaggerGenOptionsExtensions.IncludeXmlComments(SwaggerGenOptions swaggerGenOptions, Func`1 xmlDocFactory, Boolean includeControllerXmlComments)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SwaggerGenOptionsExtensions.IncludeXmlComments(SwaggerGenOptions swaggerGenOptions, String filePath, Boolean includeControllerXmlComments)
   at WebApplication3.Startup.<>c.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(SwaggerGenOptions c) in C:\Users\EXJ508\source\repos\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Startup.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConfigureSwaggerGeneratorOptions..ctor(IOptions`1 swaggerGenOptionsAccessor, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitNoCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SwaggerGenServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddSwaggerGen>b__0_1(IServiceProvider s)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_3(IDictionary`2 namedArgs) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 72
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 59
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 111
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GetExecutingAssembly()` or `GetCallingAssembly()` or pass in the assembly name as a parameter in your C# code.

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"GetEntryAssembly: {Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName}");
```

results in:

```
GetEntryAssembly: dotnet-swagger, Version=5.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

because the `GetEntryAssembly` is that of the swagger cli tool you use and that is why it is looking for `dotnet-swagger.xml`.